# selinux is preventing from execute access on the file centos

Tags: centos, centos-7, tomcat

I want to launch the Tomcat service on CentOS with the cmdlet :

```
systemctl start tomcat.service
```

but i get the error

> Failed to start Apache ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
> (code=exited, status=203/EXEC).

and the log through the command  :

```
Journalctl -xe
```

is stating that

> Selinux is preventing (artup.sh) from execute access on the file
> startup.sh

given that i can start any other service on my CentOS what could be the problem for my tomcat service ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just disable selinux and see whether it works, but that is not a recommended way.

please check the following links for further recommendations
https://serverfault.com/questions/994802/selinux-is-preventing-to-start-tomcat